# Dynamically Disable Asm.js

Tags: javascript, benchmarking, emscripten, asm.js

I would like to run a a benchmarkjs test on a program that is cross compiled from emscripten.

Is there a way to disable the asm.js optimizations to run it with and without asm?

Comment: What browser or environment are you testing in?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @brianxautumn did this solved? I also want to remove the asm code generated by emscripten.